How to integrate Code Beamer Ticket ID and its status with GitLab?
Whenever developer commits a code to GitLab, it should validate with the Ticket ID of the codebeamer and check the ticket status (open,close,inprogress). Gitlab should allow the push operation based on the Ticket status of the CodeBeamer. Push operation has to be allowed only for the OPEN ticket status
Hence, how to interlink the Ticket ID status of the codebeamer with GitLab also validate status of it

You can write a CI job to check if the status of the Ticket and then fail the job according to the need. Also there is a setting to prevent merging when there are failed pipelines
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/auto_merge.html#require-a-successful-pipeline-for-merge
This will ensure changes are not pushed to the main branch in case the requirement is not satisfied.

Is there any way to integrate Code Beamer ticket status with Gitlab or we have to write only CI Job to check it
